# C - Writing strings in a function. Error:expected expression

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

I'm trying to write a function that extracts several characters from a string and assigns it to another string.

The code:

```
// Problem 10.4
// String extraction function

#include <stdio.h>

void substring (char source[], int start, int count, char result[])
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= count; ++i) {
        result[i] = source[start];
    }

    result[i+1] = '\0';
}

int main (void)
{
    void substring (char source[], int start, int count, char result[]);
    char source[] = "character", result[80];
    int start, count;

    substring(source[], 4, 3, result[]);

    printf("%s\n", result);

    return 0;

}
```

Xcode is telling me that the line

```
substring(source[], 4, 3, result[]);
```

is "expecting an expression" and it won't let me compile.

I'm confused because my function isn't returning any value (it's doing the string assignment within itself and since it's a string, doesn't that mean pointers are being passed to the function? In which case doesn't that mean that the strings themselves are being modified and not local copies? If the original strings are being modified, why then would I have to return a value?)

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, although I suspect is has something to do with the fact that I'm not syntactically passing pointers to my function.

Thanks in advance for any insight you can offer.

Comment: First, why is there a `void substring (char source[], int start, int count, char result[]);` in main() and second try `substring(source, 4, 3, result);` instead of `substring(source[], 4, 3, result[]);`

Comment: Consider working through a proper tutorial on arrays and pointers: http://pweb.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the way to pass arrays to functions.

You are using source[]   this '[]' is not needed.

Arrays are passed as references in C. When you pass an array source[] (fun(source)), its base address will be passed into the function just like the case with pointers.

```
substring(source, 4, 3, result);
```

Also, your code results in "aaaa" by invoking above call. You need to increment start variable in loop and don't forget that index starts from 0 that way if you mean start=4, it starts from 5th character 'a' and results in "acte".

Code:

```
    // Problem 10.4
// String extraction function

#include <stdio.h>

void substring (char source[], int start, int count, char result[])
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= count; ++i) {
        result[i] = source[start++];
    }

    result[i+1] = '\0';
}

int main (void)
{
    void substring (char source[], int start, int count, char result[]);
    char source[] = "character", result[80];
    int start, count;

    substring(source, 4, 3, result);

    printf("%s\n", result);

    return 0;

}
```

All the best...

Answer (score 1):

```
void substring (char source[], int start, int count, char result[])
{
    int i;

//  for (i = 0; i <= count; ++i) {
//      result[i] = source[start];
    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        result[i] = source[start++];//start++ or start + i
    }

//  result[i+1] = '\0';
    result[i] = '\0';
}

int main (void)
{
//    void substring (char source[], int start, int count, char result[]);
    char source[] = "character", result[80];
//    int start, count;

//    substring(source[], 4, 3, result[]);
    substring(source, 4, 3, result);

    printf("%s\n", result);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`source[]` is not a valid expression, it is a valid identifier declaration of an array, nothing more.

You need to pass a correct argument to the function, which is of type `char[]`:

```
substring(source, 4, 3, result);
```